# arXiv number does not appear in the bibliography

Tags: overleaf, ieeetran, bibliographystyle, arxiv

I am using the following bibliography style in overleaf

`\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}`

and the Bibtex citation for the arXiv preprint is as follows:

```
@misc{zhang2018hello,
      title={Hello Edge: Keyword Spotting on Microcontrollers}, 
      author={Yundong Zhang and Naveen Suda and Liangzhen Lai and Vikas Chandra},
      year={2018},
      eprint={1711.07128},
      archivePrefix={arXiv},
      primaryClass={cs.SD} }
```

I expected the bibliography as: `J. K. Author, “Title of paper,” year, arXiv number`

But I am getting:
`Y. Zhang, N. Suda, L. Lai, and V. Chandra, “Hello edge: Keyword spotting on microcontrollers,” 2018.`

It is not printing the arXiv number. Am I missing something?

Comment: Welcome! As far as I can see, the IEEEtran bib style doesn't know about the `eprint` and `archiveprefix` fields. Maybe you should use the `note` field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `IEEEtran` bibliography style knows nothing about the `eprint` and `archiveprefix` fields.

You need to modify your entry for the particular job.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{zhang2018hello,
  title={Hello Edge: Keyword Spotting on Microcontrollers}, 
  author={Yundong Zhang and Naveen Suda and Liangzhen Lai and Vikas Chandra},
  year={2018},
  eprint={1711.07128},
  archivePrefix={arXiv},
  primaryClass={cs.SD},
  note={arXiv 1711.07128},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{IEEEtran}

\begin{document}

\cite{Zhang2018hello}

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

I used `filecontents*` and `\jobname.bib` just to make the example self-contained. Use and modify your bib file.

[image]